from androguard.core.bytecodes.dvm import DalvikVMFormat Has androguard changed anything or any process of importing DalvikVMFormat?
when ever i try to import this from androguard.core.bytecodes.dvm import DalvikVMFormat i'm always getting this error,
i tried everything but there's always the same result, and i have to use this module for my project, can anyone help me with this ?
i tried to upgrade it to the newer version, no result,
tried to uninstall it and then again install it, same result
`> Traceback (most recent call last):

File "e:\Malware\Android\Scripts\test.py", line 6, in 
from androguard.core.bytecodes.dvm import DalvikVMFormat
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'androguard.core.bytecodes'
PS E:\Malware\Android\Scripts> `


Which Androguard version do you use (version number and project name as there are forks).
